# HTML table that is generated using a parameter

Tags: html, layout, html-table

I am trying to create a table in **file.html** which is dynamic so I have a software that has details already generated. I have three parameters. When I run it will output:

```
Name : dropdown box with all names
car : dropdown box with all cars
year : dropdown box with all years
```

I can choose any name generated in name parameter. same goes for other two.
so if parameter = name then I choose **`alex`** as a data . I can output the name I choose by doing $name.

**output**

```
alex
```

What I want :

HTML code for table that can take parameter ( we can call parameter by doing $name $year $car)

```
 1. name   2. Car  3. year
    Alex           
    Jhon         
    Tim
```

If I choose alex has a parameter and car has a BMW, I just want to add/replace car for alex to BMW and year 2020. Dont want any changes to other data .

```
**`output for alex`**
1. name   2. Car  3. year
    Alex   BMW      2020        
    Jhon         
    Tim
```

Names will be fixed so Alex, Jhoh and Tim. We could hardcode but other details are read from parameters $car and $year . If I run the code again and choose alex car has jag then I want car for alex to replace from BMW to Jag.

I have table layout but i don't know how I can replace data if I run the file again and again .

Thanks for your help. Appreciated

Comment: how you output that table?

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Comment: @SimoneRossaini there is a post build option where i can view the file. so if i have html file . i can attach that file then it reads whats inside the the file and outputs